# Using NSUserDefaults to save keystroke from a UITextView Popover

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, popover

I have a popover named `NotesViewController` which contains a `UITextView`. The popover happens when a user clicks on the `Notes` button in the `GraphViewController`.

The popover appears fine but the text in the `UITextField` disappears whenever I click off the popover and I want to be able to save it.

Examples of how to save the text either after each keystroke or when the user clicks off of the popover would also work as an answer!!

Here is what I have:

```
class NotesViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var noteView: UITextView! {
    didSet{
        defaults.setObject(noteView.text, forKey: "previousText")
        noteView.text = notes
    }
}

var notes = " " {
    didSet {
        noteView?.text = notes

    }
}

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

class GraphViewController: UIViewController, GraphViewDataSource, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{
    //
    //...
    // prepare segue for popover
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            switch identifier {
                //this is the identifier for the popover segue
                case "Show Notes":
                    if let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as? NotesViewController {
                        if let ppc = nvc.popoverPresentationController {
                            ppc.delegate = self
                        }

                        if let previousNotes = nvc.defaults.stringForKey("previousText") {
                            nvc.notes = previousNotes
                        }
                    }
                default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your text view, set the delegate for it to be your NotesViewController and implement the delegate methods which tell you when text has changed, editing started/finished. You can then cache the updated text wherever you need to. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory's comment was correct. Setting the NotesViewController as the delegate  allowed me to use methods which track changes.

This is the solution I had:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    //first check if this is the segue we are talking about here
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "Show Notes":
            if let nvc = segue.destinationViewController as? NotesViewController {
                if let ppc = nvc.popoverPresentationController {
                    ppc.delegate = self
                }

                if let previousNotes = nvc.defaults.stringForKey("textPreviouslyEnteredByUser") {
                    nvc.notes = previousNotes
                }
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class NotesViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
{
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    @IBOutlet weak var noteView: UITextView! {
        didSet {
            noteView?.text = notes
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        noteView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        defaults.setObject(textView.text, forKey: "textPreviouslyEnteredByUser")
    }


    var notes = " " {
        didSet {
        noteView?.text = notes
        }
    }
}
```